# Como tirar a cor azul de links ultilizando CSS?

Tags: html, css

Meu professor pediu para eu recriar as páginas do G1, Globo Esporte e Walmart. Ele quer os *links* "mortos, então eu uso o `<a href="#">`. O problema é que aí o conteúdo do `a` fica azul, e as páginas tem links em varias cores diferentes.

O que eu quero fazer é tirar esse Azul dos *links*, e deixar a palavra que vai virar link com a cor que ela já está.

Já usei no CSS o `text-decoration: none`, mas não resolveu. Tem alguma outra forma de resolver isso?

Comment: O simples mesmo seria já ter posto a cor nos links, e não na "palavra que vai virar link". Pode até existir uma razão para isso, mas em princípio não vejo sentido colorizar o elemento de fora para ter que remendar o de dentro em seguida.

Comment: Porque não e pra ter efeitos de mouse na pagina, e pra reproduzir so com html e css, então quando comecei a fazer fui definindo todas as cores como estão na página original, e só fui ter essa duvida, depois das paginas ja prontas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em princípio basta herdar a cor:

```
a { color: inherit; }
```

Isso fará com que o elemento tenha a cor do seu pai (que é o que eu acho que você está procurando).

Mas se não for isso, basta então atribuir cores:

```
/* link que ainda não foi visitado */
a:link {
   color: red;
}

/* link que foi visitado */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over */
a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

/* link selecionado */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Pelo que percebi, você tem tem diferentes cores para diferentes links, então basta atribuir à classe correta `a.<NOME DA CLASSE>`:

```
/* link que ainda não foi visitado */
a.botao-vermelho:link {
   color: red;
}

//...
```

Comment: a:hover, a:visited, a:focus, a:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }

Comment: Depois, de ver as respostas consegui fazer exatamente o que eu queria com o código acima.

Answer (score -5):

Basta usar o valor `currentColor` para o atributo `color`, assim ele mantém o estilo que você já definiu pra classe do botão

```css
a { 
   color: currentColor;
}
```

Comment: Tem um probleminha aqui. `currentColor` não foi feito para usar no `color`, e sim para usar o valor do `color` em OUTRA parte do elemento (por exemplo, fazer uma borda ou sombra que acompanhe a cor das letras, ou um efeito de "glow" com sombra usando current color, etc ). O seu código simplesmente é um fallback menos explícito para  `color:inherit` que já está na outra resposta.

Comment: A [documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor) pode ajudar no entendimento: _"currentColor: The value of the ‘color’ property. The used value of the ‘currentColor’ keyword is the computed value of the ‘color’ property. If the ‘currentColor’ keyword is set on the ‘color’ property itself, it is treated as ‘color: inherit’. "_ ...

Comment: ... que traduzindo é mais ou menos _"currentColor: O valor da propriedade 'color'. O valor usado pela palavra-chave 'currentColor' é o valor computado da propriedade 'color'. Se a palavra-chave 'currentColor' for usada na própria 'color', é tratada como se fosse 'color: inherit'."_